# Spring TCP Socket client not receiving data from Mainframe

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp

I am trying to use [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server) to send and receive the data to and from a Mainframe machine that uses `HEX` data to communicate. So I have the following in my configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder />

    <!-- Client side -->

    <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.SimpleGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="<ip>"
                                   serializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   deserializer="CustomSerializerDeserializer"
                                   port="${availableServerSocket}"
                                   single-use="false"
                                   so-timeout="1800000"
                                   using-nio="false" />

    <bean id="CustomSerializerDeserializer" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.CustomSerializerDeserializer" />


    <int:channel id="input" />

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                                 request-channel="input"
                                 connection-factory="client"
                                 request-timeout="1800000"
                                 reply-timeout="1800000"/>

    <!-- Server side -->

    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
                                   type="server"
                                   port="${availableServerSocket}"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
                                connection-factory="crLfServer"
                                request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
                                error-channel="errorChannel"/>

    <int:channel id="toSA" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                           ref="echoService"
                           method="test"/>

    <bean id="echoService"
          class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.EchoService" />

    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
                                      input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
                                      output-channel="toSA"/>

</beans>
```

And in my Serializer/Deserializer, I have the following content:

```
public void serialize(String input, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(buildmsg(input));
    outputStream.flush();
}

public String deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    logger.info("inside deserialize");
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    int len = dis.readInt();
    if (len > 0) {
        logger.info("len: " + decimaltohex(len));
        logger.info("data: " + data);
        byte[] b = new byte[dis.available()];
        dis.readFully(b);
        data += decimaltohex(len);
        data += byteArrayToHex(b);
    }
    logger.info("full data:" + data);
    return data;
}

public byte[] buildmsg(String body) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String header = "00000000";
    String totMsg = header + body;
    header = massageheader(decimaltohex(totMsg.length() / 2));
    totMsg = header + body;
    logger.info("sending data : " + totMsg);
    return hexStringToByteArray(totMsg);
}

public String decimaltohex(int data) {
    return Integer.toHexString(data);
}

public static String massageheader(String data) {
    String str = String.format("%8s", data).replace(' ', '0').toUpperCase();
    return str;
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
    for (byte b : a) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The input in itself is a hex string(assume so). So the message is being sent and the response also is being received properly but the output is not being passed back to the Echo Service. Why is that not happening? Is there anything wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a DEBUG log, only INFO; your log4j configuration must be wrong.

> inside deserialize

This is simply the receiving thread waiting for data; it is stuck in your for loop waiting for the mainframe to close the connection - I suggest you add some debug inside the loop.

**EDIT**

Commons-logging is missing from your POM...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or switch to log4j2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and create a log4j2 config file.

Spring Framework 5 now uses its own implementation of commons-logging that does not support log4j 1.x.

Comment: I added a correction - that is simply the reader thread sitting in your deserializer waiting for data.

Comment: your right, it was my fault with the logics. Thanks for pointing that out. I have now fixed it and the bytes are being converted to string. I can see them printed in my log but for some reason doesn't pass on to the echoservice class. Can you help me why?

Comment: You need to look at a DEBUG log; if you still can't figure it out; post the log someplace.

Comment: I have fixed the issue but I would like to know if the socket connection opens and closes on everytime I message is sent or does the connection persist? What happens is, the socket descriptor is different even though I send 2 messages in a row. This is causing issues on the Mainframe side.

Comment: If your configuration is still the same as above, you have `single-use="true"`, which means a new socket for each request; with `"false"` the same connection will persist until the mainframe closes it.

Comment: tried with that but doesnt work, the mainframe doesnt end the socket connection in anyway. I have checked with native java socket implementation, it works fine. any other ideas?

Comment: One more time - DEBUG logging should tell you what's going on.

Comment: Here is the log https://pastebin.com/aQxiajv2 if you want to have a look at the complete source, I have uploaded it to gdrive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1N6dGU7FEXsQTFTQnhNaGY5LVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Once again, this is NOT a debug log; just INFO and above. This is a smoking gun `SEVERE: Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for 192.86.33.61:6100:60158:653dbde0-8b5c-4e2e-93a9-46a46b35efcb` but without a DEBUG log, it's hard to track down the root cause. The fact that it's logged as SEVERE, not ERROR (and the pattern doesn't match your config) indicates you are not using log4j but some other logging subsystem, so the log4j.xml config is being ignored.

Comment: Spring Framework 5 no longer supports log4j 1.x out of the box; see my edits to the answer.

Comment: find the full debug log now https://pastebin.com/ruZt4ikw . Just checked the integration repo and picked the pull request changes you have done for log4j2.

Comment: I have changed the request-timeout and reply-timeout to 1800000 in tcp-outbound-gateway. Here is the new log: https://pastebin.com/qFzytMSj

Comment: any ideas on why the data isnt reaching the echo service?

Comment: I am in all-day meetings this week and won't be able to look at the logs until at least Friday. The DEBUG log should tell you what's going on as long as you put enough diagnostics in your deserializer. I suspect there is something wrong with your logic regarding the length header; on the outbound side you are sending the length data length + 4 in 8 hex chars whereas on the inbound side you are reading the length as an integer; and even then reading the total length (instead of the length - 4).

Comment: I must admit that the above logic is not the best but this is just an experiment to see if the above can be done so as to take up spring for the project. I have the debug logs but for some reason cant figure out why I cant get the data from the deserializer to the echo service. Am I missing something in my xml that routes the deserializer data to echo service?

Comment: It looks to me like it's working fine... `...TcpOutboundGateway] Response GenericMessage [payload=3001f5000...`. Why do you expect something to go to the echo service when you are sending the request to the mainframe and getting the response. The echo service is on the server side of the sample app. Change your `main` method to `System.out.println(new String(gateway.send("01F4...")));` and you'll see you are getting a response.

Comment: Oh - `Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'gw' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
logoff` - your deserializer is returning a `String` but the gateway is expecting a `byte[]` - change the gateway definition to return `String`.

Comment: thanks! that solved the problem. Now i am able to get the data into my echo service. Just one last thing. I dont want the my integration to have a server part, I need the client alone. I tried commenting out the `gatewayCrLf` and `crLfServer` but its giving me an error as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406350/spring-tcp-support-getting-exception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-abstractserve. Could you point out what I need to remove?

Comment: Remove this code from your `main` method `final AbstractServerConnectionFactory crLfServer = context.getBean(AbstractServerConnectionFactory.class);` (and some of the lines below it).

Answer (score 0):

If the mainframe doesn't close the connection at the end of the response, as it probably doesn't, the read loop will never exit. The loop needs to be aware of the expected or actual length of the response somehow.

The serializers also surely need to do some EBCDIC conversion?

Comment: Yeah - we already covered the EBCDIC conversion on his [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367943/spring-tcp-client-without-transformer/45373462#45373462).